# VS2022 TypeScript Build page says: "An error occurred trying to load the page. Illegal characters in path."

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.2.6

So I've tried unloading the project and to see if there is anything out of order. But nothing jumps at me. (Customer name removed)
[image]

This is what it looks like in 2019:
[image]

And this is what I get in 2022

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not an issue on vs 17.3 anymore.